# Session times out after 5/6 mins - Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I am having a similar issue. In testing environment it worked just by updating the session.js from config (maxAge:24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ~ 24hrs. 
In Prod it doesn't work at all. After 5/6 mins the application times out the user and you need to log in again. 
I have modified http.js by adding a custom middleware just after 'session' middleware. 
No luck. I am using sails.js 0.12.14. Really desperate as my application should go live this week.
[my http.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DCKi.png)

Comment: Are you using memory backed or redis backed session store?

Comment: I managed to sort out the issue DB server in Prod was killing any unused connection after 10 mins, in Dev it was set to 8hr. This is the reason why end users were kicking out of the site after few minutes. All my setting in session.js were fine, the DB server was problematic ...

Comment: 1 more thing, it is sad that few people here prefer criticizing other rather than helping. If you don't want to help don't comment please ...

Comment: Hi Zac just saw your comment. Thanks for your reply it is sorted now it was nothing to do with memory or redis. I actually use memory one as I didn't need to store the user details. Anyway the issue was our DB server in Prod was timing out any open connection after 10 mins. It was very strange because the same code was in DEV and PROD. :-)